# How can I generate a Dogecoin address from a Litecoin private key?

Tags: litecoin, dogecoin, private-key-import

I'd like to do the following:

- I use `dumpprivkey` to get the private key from `Litecoin` wallet.
- I import this private key into `Dogecoin` wallet
- Which will generate a new Dogecoin address. Both will share the same private key.

The most related post I found is: [What happens if you send Bitcoin to a Litecoin address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/16933/what-happens-if-you-send-bitcoin-to-a-litecoin-address)

However, when I try to directly import, it will give me  the 
error:
`{"code":-5,"message":"Invalid private key encoding"}`

So now, how can I dump the private key and decode into hex and move the prefix from "L" to "D" and regenerate a WIF for dogecoin?

Is there any existing solution for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume we have this compressed Litecoin WIF private key:  **T4DRLwPgnkg9jyivjbbnmqJZjHRxeYTy4idAV5uwEuFdyJBGuxXE**.

```
% echo T4DRLwPgnkg9jyivjbbnmqJZjHRxeYTy4idAV5uwEuFdyJBGuxXE | bx base58check-decode
```

**`wrapper
{
    checksum 625264444
    payload 22b207aa76eb058876c667dc64ab8eeaa0a073bc018561c2463d438a0444b70501
    version 176
}`**

**ANSWER for Doge WIF Key:**

```
% bx base58check-encode -v 158 22b207aa76eb058876c667dc64ab8eeaa0a073bc018561c2463d438a0444b70501
```

**`QPn542uVdzBgCfV6nEViShboFTpDd1at8mQpQugEQHgpuLbsgcZe`**

**VALIDATION CHECK:**

```
% echo QPn542uVdzBgCfV6nEViShboFTpDd1at8mQpQugEQHgpuLbsgcZe | bx base58check-decode
```

**`wrapper
{
    checksum 2298567751
    payload 22b207aa76eb058876c667dc64ab8eeaa0a073bc018561c2463d438a0444b70501
    version 158
}`**

Examine [158](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table), [base58check-decode](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-base58check-decode) and [base58check-encode](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-base58check-encode) for more details.

Comment: it is awesome, it really help. and also need the  altcoin mapping url is here: https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table , However, it is not quite complete, anyone knows how to get the extra WIF version value?