# Help! I've sent ltc to bcc address

Tags: litecoin, public-key, wallet-recovery, cross-chain-recovery

I've been stupid..

I've sent ltc's from one wallet (litebit) to a bcc address from my other wallet (btc.com) by mistake.
The btc.com wallet only supports BTC and BCC

The address is 386BxgQy7samGg3L7adCDMEMW7ndEocDC7 and i can see the ltc's in this address by using blockcypher.

I have the recover pdf file from the btc.com wallet containing:
Wallet identifier (v3)
Encrypted primary seed (60 words)
Backup seed (24 words)
Encrypted recovery secret (60 words)
BTC wallet public key
Password encrypted secret (60 words)

I've tried contacting btc.com and they suggested using ltc-recovery.blocktrail.com which i did.. Result after implementing my seeds etc was:

------ Discover Wallet Funds

Scan for funds to recover from addresses in the wallet.

The first address of your wallet is: MSW5x2ggVAagygz24kWhP7PgZXCbFELP1S,
please provide this if you ever need to contact support about help using this tool.
No Funds Found

A balance of 0.00000000 LTC was found after searching 150 addresses. -----

For the rest btc.com isn't responding. 
Note: I only used the wallet once and the first address (see above "outcome" from blocktrail) is different than the address now containing my ltc's?

I also tried "coinomi" wallet to restore a wallet using my btc.com seeds (i'm not sure which seeds to use, so i've tried them all) there is no error and the wallet opens every time, only with 0 ltc's.

I've found a simulair question on this site but with no solution:( It does talk about a private key, did i get a private key and didn't see it or is that something i can look up any where? A private key is not the same as my seeds or recovery secret is it? (Except for the public key, the seeds and secrets in my back up pdf are words)

Can i somehow acces the specific address containing my ltc's and a different wallet? I have the seeds from my btc.com wallet back up..

I'm a newbe at this and can sure use some help!!!?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your money is recoverable, and I don't know too much about the specifics of Litecoin, but I believe there is hope.  First, I think I should explain what appears to have happened (for anyone else who finds this question, since you seem to have a handle on it).

The address you sent to is a [pay-to-script-hash (P2SH) address](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/p2sh-address), which according to comments on [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/16934/24974) are valid on both chains.  This does not mean that you sent LTC to a Bitcoin (or Bitcoin Cash) address.  This means that you sent LTC to an identical, yet valid, *Litecoin* address.  However, this address is not one that currently has a private key stored in *your* Litecoin wallet.  This is why you would not expect to see the money there.

This means that in theory, you could claim the coins on the Litecoin blockchain by importing the private key(s) that correspond to the address on the *Bitcion* blockchain...which it sounds like are private keys that you have in your Bitcoin wallet.  I know nothing about the wallet services you are using, but if you can export your keys from the Bitcoin wallet that generated the address in question, and then import that particular key into your Litecoin wallet, you should be able to claim the coins.

It all sounds like this is what you are already attempting, but you are starting by seeding a new wallet.  If this isn't working, it could be because one of the wallet providers is using a non-standard way of generating addresses from wallet seeds.  You may want to try writing some code of your own (using a utility such as https://github.com/prusnak/bip32utils) to generate your own addresses based on your recovered seeds.  This may help you to find the specific private key for the address in question, and from there you can import that key directly into the Litecoin reference client and claim the coins.  This may or may not be worth the effort, depending on how much money is at stake.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi jestin, thanks for your reply and answer! I'm glad that there is still some hope... I've been trying to find my private keys in my wallet but there are no other options then the bare minimum, send receive import pincode change etc. Nothing about private keys or exporting them (that i can find).

Comment: I've been looking on the github site but writing my own code is way above my skill level to be honest:S I've found a site/program that lets me create keys but i'm not sure which seed to fill in where and when i try different options the addresses don't match mine (containing the ltc's). I don't even know if i need to fill in, making keys for bitcoin/bcc or ltc, and thinking about it, it doesn't feel safe to just fill in my seeds in some program online..

Comment: Maybe there are safe options/links that someone knows of, ones that work completely offline? Or something especially for P2SH addresses? I've asked btc.com if they can help me finding my private key, but still waiting for reply.. It's been quite a search i can tell you that haha. thanks again and if some one knows anything to help i would sure appreciate it! regards Koen