# I sent litecoin to my bitcoin address, on my nano ledger

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, litecoin, wallet-recovery, cross-chain-recovery

So I am very new to cryptocurrencies and have already made my first mistake.

I used shapeshift.io to transfer bitcoin to litecoin, and entered a bitcoin address as the recipient to receive the litecoin. This bitcoin address is on my nano ledger s.

Is there a way to somehow fix this? The only things close to answers I have found are the reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6sfnl2/segwit_has_been_locked_in_congratulations_everyone/dleu77d/

and this stack exchange question
[What happens if you send Bitcoin to a Litecoin address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/16933/what-happens-if-you-send-bitcoin-to-a-litecoin-address)

However I am not sure if these will apply to me.

I am feeling very stupid, and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: An update:

I have followed the first three steps in the reddit guide, typing 0 in the "internal / external" field (all under the BIP44 tab so far). This gives me a BIP32 derivation path of m/44'/0'/0'/0. Then if I enter this BIP32 derivation path under the BIP32 tab, the list of derived addresses is 2000+ long. How am I supposed to find the private key that matches exactly the last segment in the BIP32 derivation path, as per the guide from reddit? It seems my BIP32 derivation path is missing one field, is that correct?