# Litecoin withdraw to a bitcoin wallet by mistake how can I fix?

Tags: litecoin, blockchain-fork

Litecoin withdraw transaction where bitcoin address was mistakenly used and a new litecoin address was created. Once on the chain it took the bitcoin address and created a litecoin address still connected to the bitcoin address. I know there is a way to correct  and if anyone has more information it would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if you send Bitcoin to a Litecoin address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/16933/what-happens-if-you-send-bitcoin-to-a-litecoin-address)